# How to return a response from _create api rest method

Tags: api, rest-api

By default this method returns an empty JSON , i want to how to return some response such as "correct" or "fail" , for example

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, or at least how this part was designed to be used in Magento, is to check for the HTTP response code for success/failures, and use the Location in the response header to make another call to retrieve the newly created customer details.